# Discord bot gives me a false message and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making my first discord bot, and I asked my friend to test kick/ban commands, I jokingly, tried banning him, now he had admin privileges so he couldn't get banned but the bot still sent the message confirming the ban, both of us are confused and I want to fix this so I don't get this message in the future.

[image]

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "kick command",
    execute(message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            message.channel.send("You do not have the permission to execute this command");
            return;
        }
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (member) {
            const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarger.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked!");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You could not kick that member");
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```js
const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
memberTarger.kick();
message.channel.send("User has been kicked!");
```

With

```
const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
if(!memberTarger.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')){
  memberTarger.kick();
  message.channel.send("User has been kicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the bot can kick/ban a member with the [`.kickable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable) or [`.bannable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=bannable) properties of a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

See the example below and give it a try:

```js
const memberToKick; // Should hold the value of the GuildMember you want to kick.

if (memberToKick.kickable) {
  memberToKick.kick()
    .then(() => {
      message.channel.send('Member successfully kicked!');
    }).catch((e) => {
      message.channel.send(`I couldn't kick the member for some reason. Here is the error: ${e}`);
    });
} else {
  message.channel.send('Sorry, I don\'t have permission to kick this member...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not perfect but it should work

if you go to the discord developer portal, go to OAuth2 and then click bot and scroll down and select administrator or kick members
then kick the bot and invite it again
This is to make sure your bot has permission to kick
and finally go to your server settings and make sure that your bot's role is above the role you want to kick (i always fall for that)